# How to remove all Extended ASCII characters, but not umlauts?

Tags: java, ascii

I'd like to remove all `ASCII` extended characters from an input. (reference: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-a-umlaut-diaeresis-a-umlaut-lowercase-ascii-code-132.html).

I could therefore use `CharMatcher.ASCII`, but further I'd like to keep german umlauts, which are contained within the extended char set.
So, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: As I wrote, I tried the ASCII matcher, eg: `replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");` But I don't know how to not replace umlauts.

Comment: No, you didn't say that you tried that, and you didn't post any code. So, the `replaceAll` you mention works except for umlauts? Can't you just add that? (`replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}&]", "");`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use the Guava [`CharMatcher`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class for this task, then you can compose matchers using the `and(CharMatcher)` and `or(CharMatcher)` methods, etcetera.  For example:

```
CharMatcher asciiPlusUmlauts = 
    CharMatcher.ASCII.or(CharMatcher.anyOf("ÄäÖöÜüß"));
```

You get the idea?

Comment: Great, that's promising. Do you also know how to convert any character to its "uniform" instead of replacing it with a fixed char? Eg: `Ç -> C, á -> a`...

Comment: @membersound comments are not the place to ask a different question. Search first, and if you don't find an answer ask a new question.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm not going to answer that comment.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a whitelist:

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}ÄäÖöÜüß]", "");
```

The character class is all ASCII chars plus the umlauts (and I threw in esszet too)

In action:

```
System.out.println("a\tb© ½Ü, ß".replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}ÄäÖöÜüß]", ""));
```

Output:

```
a   b Ü, ß
```

Comment: It's not clear that control characters are to be replaced. Maybe `[^\\p{ASCII}ÄäÖöÜüß]`?

Comment: @Keppil you've got a deal

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Lucene's `org.apache.lucene.analysis.ASCIIFoldingFilter`. It does exactly what you require in an efficient way. It does the folding by checking for each `char` whether or not it is smaller than `\u0080` (i.e. character code point 128). If it is, you can leave it as it is (it is an ASCII character), otherwise you have to handle it in some way. For more details on the Unicode Latin character take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_characters_in_Unicode